# Does $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) = a$ and $\lim_{t\to t_0}g(t) = x_0$ imply $\lim_{t\to t_0}f(g(t)) = a$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

> Let:
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> &\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) = a \tag1 \\
> &\lim_{t\to t_0}g(t) = x_0 \tag2
> \end{align*}
> $$
>   Does $(1)$ and $(2)$ imply the following:
>   $$
> \lim_{t\to t_0}f(g(t)) = a\tag 3
> $$

While considering this problem I was thinking that the implication should follow at least for the continuous functions. But there is no constraint for $f(x)$ to be continuous in the problem statement.

The answer section does provide a hint on how to show that the implication doesn't follow. However, I'm not sure how to use it. It suggests considering $f(g(t))$ as $t\to 0$ for the following specific functions $f(x)$ and $g(t)$:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
{1\over q},\ \ x={p\over q}\ \text{and} \ p\perp q\\
0, \ \ x\in \left\{\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q\right\}
\end{cases}\\
g(t) = \begin{cases}
1,\ t \ne 0\\
0,\ t=0
\end{cases}
$$

Here $a\perp b$ denotes that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime and $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ is the set of irrational numbers.

I've started by consider $f(x)$. Since rational numbers are dense in $\mathbb R$ there are infinitely many of them in any neighborhood of some point $x_0$. It follows that:
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = 0
$$

Also the limit of $g(t)$ at $t_0 = 0$ is:
$$
\lim_{t\to t_0}g(t) = 0
$$

I'm lost here. As a gut feeling, I think there might be some issues with $f(x)$ around $0$ because of the requirement for $p\perp q$ which would eventually lead to some kind of contradiction, but not sure tho.

Could someone please help me untangle that problem?

Comment: In your case, $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=0$ for any real $x_0,$ but it is not because "there are infinitely many [rationals] in any neighborhood of some point $x_0.$" Rather, the limit is $0$ because the denominators of the rationals near but not equal $x_0$ approach infinity.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Unfortunately I have nothing as an addition to the problem statement, that is how it appears in the book. It only asks whether or not (1) and (2) imply (3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't even need $g$ to be discontinuous. Let $g(x) = 1$, $t_0 = 0$, $x_0 = 1$, $a = 0$. Then we have $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} f(x) = a$, $\lim\limits_{t \to t_0} g(t) = x_0$.

But $\lim\limits_{t \to t_0} f(g(t)) = \lim\limits_{t \to t_0} f(1) = 1 \neq 0 = a$.

For the statement to be true, in general we need either $f$ be continuous in $x_0$, or $g$ not be constant in any punctured neighborhood of $t_0$.

Comment: Technically, we need $g$ is not constant in any punctured interval $(t_0-\epsilon,t_0+\epsilon)\setminus\{t_0\}.$